# How to rip Blu-Ray discs using open source software

Tags: ripping, blu-ray, h.264

How can one rip Blu-Rays that he or she owns via AnyDVD as the decoder? Open source would be prefer but not require. H.264 video codec is preferred.

Current Software: [AnyDVD HD](http://bit.ly/qDnLAx) & [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

Disclaimer: I have no intention of illegally distributing the end result. I'm currently working in Afghanistan. I would like to rip my Blu-Rays and send them home safely. I have already rip my 200+ DVD collection.

Comment: Are these "protected" blu-ray discs?

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5559007/the-hassle+free-guide-to-ripping-your-blu+ray-collection

Comment: six years later and we still have no fully open source Blu-Ray ripping tool? :(

Answer (score 1):

Closest I've found so far is free, but not open source:

[DVDFab HD Decrypter (free version)](http://www.dvdfab.com/en/hd-decrypter.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are many programs out there that allow you to make copies of your Blu-ray discs and let you watch them the way you want to view them.  The combination of MakeMKV (30-day trial, lifetime license is about $50) and Handbrake (open source) can help you get the job done effortlessly.

What I'm using now is a program entitled LosslessCopy. I've had the pleasure of using the program these past 2 years for ripping my movie library and add them to plex library for streaming. Besides the multi-track mkv output, it also offers lots of optimized profiles like h.264 mp4, hevc mp4, etc. It works very well and I haven't really had any problems. Conversion speed seems fine and the videos look good. Give a try!